How to make multiple stanzas of lyrics stop overlapping?
When lilypond lays out lyrics, it seems to only consider the notes, not other lyrics, which can result in "overlap" between syllables in different stanzas. As a minimal example:
\version "2.24.1"

<<
    { c' c' }
    \addlyrics { Why???????????????? This }
    \addlyrics { is bad!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! }
>>

The word "bad" appears under the trailing "???"s, which is both ugly and confusing.
This can even force a word past the bar line in extreme cases like this, though in the real world it is somewhat less likely since the notes are just a little further apart. But a lot of lyrics use iambs (and thus something like \partial 4) and this happens in the middle of a couplet (which is not long enough for it to be sensible to break the music line, unlike between couplets).
I tried using " quotes " containing space but that makes it off-center unless it's on both sides (which punishes the innocent syllable following).
(for some reason, it seems like all the questions about Lilypond lyric spacing are trying to remove space, but I'm trying to add it)

What's wrong with a temporary \override LyricText.X-offset?

The code in your question demonstrates a problem case, but it is an artificial example (and somewhat pathological).

My guess at what is happening is that LilyPond is tying to space the notes and lyrics correctly, but some metric is tripping and causes it to give up.
Even with those “lyrics”, if you change the line with the music block to have some trivial context (with a well placed break),  e.g. { c'2 c' | R1 | \break R1 | }, you can see that LilyPond is able to space the notes and lyrics correctly:


If you have a “real” example that you can’t fix like this, I suggest that you add that to your question; there might be another simple workaround, such as shrinking the font size.
